# Azure functions java read file inside a project / resources?

Tags: java, jar, azure-functions

How can I read a file inside a project ( resources folder ) when I host it as an azure function?

I tried with:

```
public static File GetFileFromResources(String pathFromResources) {
    File file;
    ClassLoader classLoader = FilesHelper.class.getClassLoader();
    URL url = classLoader.getResource(pathFromResources);
    file = new File(url.getFile());
    return file;
}
```

However I get an exception:

```
[09.08.2020 18:05:08] Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Maciej-pc\Desktop\AzureFunctionsss\hl7edytorFunctions\target\azure-functions\hl7edytorFunctions-1596901248640\file:\C:\Users\Maciej-pc\Desktop\AzureFunctionsss\hl7edytorFunctions\target\azure-functions\hl7edytorFunctions-1596901248640\hl7edytorFunctions-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!\somethinng.xsl (Nazwa pliku, nazwa katalogu lub skladnia 
etykiety woluminu jest niepoprawna)
[09.08.2020 18:05:08]   at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
[09.08.2020 18:05:08]   at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:219)
[09.08.2020 18:05:08]   at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:157)
[09.08.2020 18:05:08]   at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:112)
```

The filename or folder name is incorrect.

I testing it on the local machine. I would like to get it works on localhost and Azure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok here is a working method:

```
public static String GetFileInStringFromResources(String pathToResources) throws IOException {

    // this is the path within the jar file
    InputStream input = FilesHelper.class.getResourceAsStream("/resources/" + pathToResources);

    // here is inside IDE
    if (input == null) {
        input = FilesHelper.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(pathToResources);
    }

    //here you can return (InputStream) input or you can return as string
    //return input;

    // convert InputStream to String
    ByteArrayOutputStream result = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = input.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        result.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    return result.toString("UTF-8");

}
```

Comment: Where do you find the FilesHelper class?

Comment: Is the name of class where you put GetFileInStringFromResources

Comment: thanks, will post what worked for me in Groovy. New to Java so I will be captain obvious

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me in Groovy:

```
public String GetFileInStringFromResources(String pathToResource) throws IOException {
    // this is the path within the jar file
    InputStream input = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(pathToResource)

    // here is from inside IDE
    if (input == null) {
        input = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(pathToResource)
    }

    return input.getText("UTF-8")
}
```

Note the resource needs to be saved in the official Maven resources directory.
https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/resource-directory.html